# Sliver app bar background color not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a sliver app bar with the background of the same color as the color or the contents that are scrolled under it, therefore making the appbar blend with the contents. Is there any way I can completely hide the contents that are beneath the SliverAppBar?

So as you can see below, the background color of the main app bar is the same as the background color of what follows(the contents).

```
CustomScrollView(
      controller: controller,
      slivers: [
// This should be the main app bar where the contents have to be behind it
        SliverAppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 36,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: showChatTitle
                ? const Text(
                    'Chats',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.black),
                  )
                : null,
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.002),
            leading: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, top: 10),
              child: const Text(
                'Edit',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 12.5),
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.edit_calendar,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

// Contents follows now
        SliverAppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 45,
          elevation: 0,
          pinned: pinChatText,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.002),
          title: const Text(
            'Chats',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverPadding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          sliver: SliverAppBar(
              toolbarHeight: searchBarHeight,
              floating: false,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
              foregroundColor: Colors.black,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
              title: Text.rich(
                TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(textColorOpacity),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    WidgetSpan(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(textColorOpacity),
                        size: 17,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const TextSpan(
                      text: ' Search',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ),
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8, top: 15),
              child: Row(children: const [
                Text(
                  'Broadcast Lists',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Text(
                  'New Group',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
                children: const [
                  ChatItem(),
                  Divider(
                    indent: 50,
                    thickness: 0.4,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ))
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Please include codes

Comment: which color do u need for ur silverapp bar

Comment: A grey color with a reduced opacity

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```dart
SliverAppBar(
    scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade50,
    .
    .
    .
)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can try it with code:

> ```
> NestedScrollView(
>                   controller: _scrollController,
>                   headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
>                     return <Widget>[
>                       SliverAppBar(
>                         expandedHeight: 200.0,
>                         floating: false,
>                         pinned: true,
>                         backgroundColor: Colors.red,
>                         flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
>                             centerTitle: true,
>                             title: Text("text sample",
>                                 style: TextStyle(
>                                   color: isShrink ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
>                                   fontSize: 16.0,
>                                 )),
>                             background: CachedNetworkImage(
>                               imageUrl:
>                                   'http://preprod.tibib-live.com/medias/cached-media/medium/5bea5964109aa-c827b05facc3781485e584dac2f4dddc.png',
>                               fit: BoxFit.cover,
>                             )),
>                       ),
>                     ];
>                   },
>                   body: Center(
>                     child: Text("hello world"),
>                   ),
>                 );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I had to use Colors.grey.shade50 instead of Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.003)

Check code below

```
CustomScrollView(
      controller: controller,
      slivers: [
// This should be the main app bar where the contents have to be behind it
        SliverAppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 36,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: showChatTitle
                ? const Text(
                    'Chats',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.black),
                  )
                : null,
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade50, // Used shade here
            leading: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, top: 10),
              child: const Text(
                'Edit',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 12.5),
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.edit_calendar,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

// Contents follows now
        SliverAppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 45,
          elevation: 0,
          pinned: pinChatText,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.002),
          title: const Text(
            'Chats',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverPadding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          sliver: SliverAppBar(
              toolbarHeight: searchBarHeight,
              floating: false,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
              foregroundColor: Colors.black,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
              title: Text.rich(
                TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(textColorOpacity),
                  ),
                  children: [
                    WidgetSpan(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(textColorOpacity),
                        size: 17,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const TextSpan(
                      text: ' Search',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ),
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8, top: 15),
              child: Row(children: const [
                Text(
                  'Broadcast Lists',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Text(
                  'New Group',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
                children: const [
                  ChatItem(),
                  Divider(
                    indent: 50,
                    thickness: 0.4,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ))
      ],
    );
```